# Inserir registros cart codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Tenho o seguinte PHP

```
if($this->input->post('stock_unity_push')=='0'){
    $stock_unity_push = 0;
} else {
    $stock_unity_push = str_replace(".", "", str_replace("R$ ", "", $this->input->post('stock_unity_push')));
    $stock_unity_push = number_format((float)$stock_unity_push, 2, '.', '');
}

$data = array(
    'id'      => $this->input->post('product_id'),
    'qty'     => $this->input->post('stock_purchase'),
    'price'   => ($stock_unity_push) ? $stock_unity_push : '0',
    'name'    => 'product_'.$this->input->post('product_id')
    //'options' => array('supplier' => $this->input->post('supplier'))
);

$this->cart->insert($data);
```

Mas para adicionar ao carrinho, ele adiciona apenas um registro, e substitui o cart atual. Estou usando o cart do codeigniter.

Answer (score 1):

Segundo a [documentação](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/cart.html) a maneira de adicionar mais de um item é fazendo assim.

```
$data = array(
        array(
                'id'      => 'sku_123ABC',
                'qty'     => 1,
                'price'   => 39.95,
                'name'    => 'T-Shirt',
                'options' => array('Size' => 'L', 'Color' => 'Red')
        ),
        array(
                'id'      => 'sku_567ZYX',
                'qty'     => 1,
                'price'   => 9.95,
                'name'    => 'Coffee Mug'
        ),
        array(
                'id'      => 'sku_965QRS',
                'qty'     => 1,
                'price'   => 29.95,
                'name'    => 'Shot Glass'
        )
);
```

Porém você pode utilizar a função [array_push](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-push.php) para montar seu $data e somente no final chamar o método insert.

Comment: Até seria o certo, mas aí como eu faria no meu PHP?